# Pages list, content types and custom field display names

Tags: content-type, display-name

While investigating [SPList multiple content types - "Column does not exist" error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47534/splist-multiple-content-types-column-does-not-exist-error), I discovered something odd. Background:

- I'm using the SharePoint Publishing feature
- I have a custom ContentType, NewsPage, that extends ArticlePage
- The NewsPage ContentType adds a field - NewsCategory - with a static name of "NewsCategory" and a display name of "Nyhetskategori" (swedish)
- I have a site definition for a News site, and the NewsPage ContentType is bound to the Pages list of the News site

If I go to "Site Actions" -> "View All Site Content", open the "Pages" list/documnt library, and then go to "Library Settings" there are two sections:

Content Types - lists the "Page", "Article Page" and "News Page" types, as expected

Columns - lists all columns from all the Content Types, but they are listed with their *static names*, not their *display names*, as I've seen on other sharepoint installations. Is there any way to control this? I want to be able to iterate over the Pages list and get pageListItem["Nyhetskategori"], i.e. access the field using the display name.

Comment: What's language settings / variations / language packs are you using? Could it be that your custom display name isn't showing because it's not set in a resource file with the proper language identifier? This thought was triggered by your mentioning of the Swedish display name.

Comment: I'm using the swedish language pack, and the site is configured to use Swedish as main language. I'm creating the ContentType programmatically and I'm not using resource files.

Comment: Ok. In that case I'm not sure what's going wrong. Unless someone else is going to answer I'd recommend contacting support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lot of troubles getting field titles right, but [this blog entry](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2011/11/14/splist-title-property-spfield-displayname-property-not-updating/) pointed me in the right direction.